# Ошибка в супер простой строке

Tags: python

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new('RGB', (28, 28), color = 'white')

green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

k = 0;
for i in range(28):
  for j in range(28):
    xy = (i, j)
    v = vals[k]
    if v > 0:
      img.putpixel((xy, green * v)
    elif v < 0:
      img.putpixel((xy, red * v)
    k += 1

img.save('test.png')
```

Ошибка в строке elif v < 0:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

у вас не хватает закрывающихся скобок

```
if v > 0:
    img.putpixel((xy, green * v)) 
elif v < 0:
    img.putpixel((xy, red * v))
```